# Android studio navigation editor is not showing the fragment's attributes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-editor

I am using **Navigation Editor** in the android studio and my android studio version is `3.3.2`.

my problem is when I add a fragment to the navigation editor, the attributes of the fragment are not showing in design mode. look at the picture:

[image]

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <fragment id="@+id/currentWeatherFragment2"
              name="ir.houmansanati.forecastmvvm.ui.weather.current.CurrentWeatherFragment"
              label="current_weather_fragment" tools:layout="@layout/current_weather_fragment"/>
    <fragment id="@+id/futureListWeatherFragment4"
              name="ir.houmansanati.forecastmvvm.ui.weather.future.list.FutureListWeatherFragment"
              label="future_list_weather_fragment" tools:layout="@layout/future_list_weather_fragment"/>
    <fragment id="@+id/futureDetailWeatherFragment2"
              name="ir.houmansanati.forecastmvvm.ui.weather.future.detail.FutureDetailWeatherFragment"
              label="future_detail_weather_fragment" tools:layout="@layout/future_detail_weather_fragment"/>
    <fragment id="@+id/settingsFragment2" name="ir.houmansanati.forecastmvvm.ui.setting.SettingsFragment"
              label="SettingsFragment"/>
</navigation>
```

as you see my fragments in XML have name and label and id attributes but all of them are labeled as `fragment`. even when I set the attributes from the design mode after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the text is gone but it changes in XML text.

I have tried `Invalidate Caches/Restart` but the problem still exists.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `id=`, `name=`, and `label=`. As per the [Implementing Navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Identify-destinations), these need to be `android:id=`, `android:name=`, and `android:label=`, respectively.

Note that your topmost `<navigation>` element must also contain `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in order to use the `android:` prefix.